# What are the essential Clojure libraries to learn beyond the basics of "core"

Tags: learning, lisp, clojure

I am teaching myself Clojure. I've started using [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen), I'm working on [Clojure Koans](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans), plan to do [LabREPL](https://github.com/relevance/labrepl) next, and will have a look at [Noir](https://github.com/ibdknox/noir).

My question is: what are the essential "must know" Clojure libraries and functions to know beyond those covered in the above learning plan?

Looking at [Clojure Contrib](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib), there are large number of libraries. As a professional (or OSS) Clojure developer, which do you find yourself using on a daily basis?  Which ones are not so useful or otherwise not commonly used (i.e. are esoteric / do not come up often in day-to-day coding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is really depends on your domain and on what you going to code.
[Avout](http://avout.io/) brings Clojure state to the distributed world.
And [Lojic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic) brings logic programming to Clojure programming language, it is an interesting project.
[Cascalog](http://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog) for example is a Clojure-based query language for Hadoop, amazing thing if you are going to do Hadoop programming.
[FleetDB](http://github.com/mmcgrana/fleetdb) is a schema free database written in Clojure.

So it is really based on what you are doing.

*(Ok, my answer covers the first section of your question).*

My list of most used contribs:
clojure.contrib.accumulators, clojure.contrib.duck-streams, clojure.contrib.lazy-xml and clojure.contrib.zip-filter.
Those are essential to me, YMMV.

Comment: What about libraries in Clojure Contrib?